# Is there such a function in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does MongoDB ever have an automatic function? For example, when my profile VIP expires, my status should be transferred to a regular user. So which function should I write Schema in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing your implementations details, but you should take a look at mongodb docs related to triggers. Alternatively, you could do it through a node cron job.

Documentation

Mongodb triggers: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/

Node-cron: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron